# Is there any way I can optimize this foreach loop that repeatedly calls a stored procedure

Tags: c#

```
    private void LoadProducts(ProductLineInfo prodLine)
    {

        DataTable products = prodLine.GetProducts(_line_id);
        DataTable emisivities = prodLine.GetEmisivityData(_line_id);
        DataTable glass = prodLine.GetGlassData(_line_id);
        DataTable gapFill = prodLine.GetGapFillData(_line_id);
        DataTable doordata = prodLine.GetDoorData(_line_id);
        DataTable specialtyData = prodLine.GetSpecialtyData(_line_id);
        DataRow[] emisivity;
        DataRow[] glassdata;
        DataRow[] door;
        DataRow[] specialty;
        DataRow[] gapFills;


        if (products.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow product in products.Rows)
            {
                emisivity = emisivities.Select("prod_id =" + product["prod_id"].ToString());
                glassdata = glass.Select("prod_id =" + product["prod_id"].ToString());
                door = doordata.Select("prod_id =" + product["prod_id"].ToString());
                specialty = specialtyData.Select("prod_id =" + product["prod_id"].ToString());
                gapFills = gapFill.Select("prod_id = " + product["prod_id"].ToString());
                _all_products.Add(new Product(product, _cpd_nbr, emisivity, glassdata, gapFills, door, specialty, _expansion_type));
            }
        }

    }
```

So essentially this code adds the items to the list after retrieving each one from a different stored procedure. Suffice it to say this task is expensive and time consuming.

Would anybody have a recommendation about how I can optimize this method?

Comment: Where is the stored procedure call?

Comment: What about setting up a view on the database side?

Comment: You should be joining these tables in your single database query.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables in the database before retrieving the data.  You could do this in the first stored procedure.

```
SELECT table_one.myID, table_one.Field1, table_two.Field1 FROM table_one
JOIN table_two ON table_one.myID = table_two.myID
```

If you cannot edit the stored procedure you could try to use a view...but if you are required to use stored procedures you would still need to incorporate the view into a stored procedure so kind of defeats the purpose.  If you can hit the DB directly and use a view, then no problem.  You could use entity framework to get to the view, or join results with lambda expressions.  If you are not familiar with Entity Framework it might be good to Google and find some tutorials.